# Disable automatic sorting of new files in Files Explorer (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

Say I have folder with `View` set to `Details`. Files are sorted by `Name` and my list is:

```
e.txt
i.txt
o.txt
```

In Windows XP, if I create or copy a new file called `a.txt`, this is placed at the bottom of the list where it is easy to find:

```
e.txt
i.txt
o.txt
a.txt
```

Alternatively, if I rename `i.txt` to `z.txt`, the file stays where it is in the list making it easy to find:

```
e.txt
z.txt
o.txt
```

To sort the files into the "correct" order, press F5, close and re-open the folder, or click the `Name` column header. Great!

But in Windows 10, automatic sorting occurs immediately without waiting for any manual trigger. This is merely unhelpful with a couple of files, but its a major headache if you have hundreds of files in a folder. A simple file rename operation is likely to dump your file god-knows-where in the list...arggh!

Curiously, this behaviour does NOT happen for files in folders on removable media such as USB sticks (ie. the behaviour there is the same as in Windows XP). This suggests that there may be a suitable registry tweak to bring back the Windows XP behaviour for normal folders.

Is there any way to bring back the Windows XP behaviour?

BTW, this question is not related to `Auto arrange` when using one of the `Icon` views.

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/446662/when-renaming-files-in-windows-7-prevent-explorer-from-instantly-resorting-the

Comment: @Sharon. Not really a duplicate. That one is over 5 years old and for Windows 7 and no solution is provided. Is there no update for Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in my Windows 10 SO Compilation 19045.2846, Windows Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0

The auto sort of files doesn't happen in Removable drives nor in PC Local Discks root folders, only in the subfolders.

Didn't find a solution yet.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks Felipe. This is a comment, not an answer. Suggest deleting your answer and add this as a comment to the main question. Up-vote the question to show you are interested in an answer.